# How to convert SSH public key from PEM to DER format?

Tags: openssl, conversion, key-authentication

I'd like to convert an existing public key (generated using `ssh-keygen`) from `PEM`-format to `DER`-format

I tried:

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -inform PEM -pubin -outform DER -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.der
```

Unfortunately this gives the following error:

```
unable to load Public Key
139946985690784:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY
```

The file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` contains a public key; `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` gives:

```
ssh-rsa ...... user@machine
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenSSH public key format is different from PEM format.  You have to run [`ssh-keygen`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1) to convert it.

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m PEM >pubkey.pem
```

Then convert it to DER format using [`openssl rsa`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html).

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in pubkey.pem -inform PEM -outform DER -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.der -RSAPublicKey_out
```

Note that you also have to specify `-RSAPublicKey_in` (not `-pubin`) and `-RSAPublicKey_out` to keep it to be RSA Public Key (PKCS#1).

Comment: Doesn't work in MacOS: `unknown option -RSAPublicKey_in`

Comment: Works on MacOS 10.14.6 with openssl 2.6.5